# Random start of definition?

Tags: text, german, random, definition

I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis and suddenly there's this random text "ärbung2.0.14" on the front page...I can't locate where its coming from. Does it look like its a counter for a definition or something? My second chapter is named "Färbungen" and if I delete this or a previous chapter the counter changes to 1.0.14. If I add a definition,remark,etc. to chapter 2 the counter changes to 2.0.15. but only if I add something to chapter 2. So I think it's like an invisible definition? My regular counter is 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 and so on, only for figures there's a third number but they also start with 1.1.1 so I don't know where the 0 in 2.0.14 comes from.
You can see the code in https://www.overleaf.com/read/gtdmxwhvkddq
I hope someone knows where the problem is coming from.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using odd characters in `\label`s. Specifically, you have

```
\label{Eckenfärbung}
```

Rather use

```
\label{Eckenfarbung}
```

Comment: thanks that fixed it!

Comment: With a *new* latex Eckenfärbung should work fine.

Comment: wouldnd't loading the `babel` package with the responding `ngerman` option solve the matter? as well as the options `utf8` (resp `T1`)?